# Which API can I use to broadcast stream without clicking the 'broadcast' button in browser?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Now, I can create a broadcast and bind a stream to it with the youtube API. I can also get the stream url.

But every time, I must publish the stream firstly and then open the browser to wait until the 'broadcast' button is enabled. And then click this button to broadcast the stream.

Can any API be used to broadcast the stream directly without clicking the button ? I checked the API document, but I didn't find any one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find I can use the API: youtube.broadcasts.insert with the parameter 'enableAutoStart: true' to broadcast without clicking the 'Go Live' button.